# Range of logarithmic function...

Tags: functions

Find the range of $f(x)=\log_{1-x}(x)\cdot\lg(1-x)$? The domain was really easy to find, but I've never done exercises with range of the function. How can I determine it?

Comment: In log1-x(x), 1-x is the base

Comment: May be it is $\log_{1-x}x$?

Comment: Please try to clarify the notation here; the question is hard to answer as written.

Comment: You may be able to look at your change-of-base formula to simplify this expression (and then consider the range of that expression)....

Comment: What does lg(1-x) mean? Is this just $\log(1-x)$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I've generally seen $\lg \equiv \log_2$.

Comment: lgx is the logarithm with base 10. In our country this notation is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $a,b$ are positive numbers different from $1,$ and if $t$ is any positive number, then $$\log_b(t)=\log_b\left(a^{\log_at}\right)=\log_a(t)\log_b(a)$$ by basic properties of logarithms. In particular, putting $t=x,a=1-x,$ and $b=10,$ we have $$f(x)=\log_{1-x}(x)\log_{10}(1-x)=\log_a(t)\log_b(a)=\log_b(t)=\log_{10}(x)$$ for all $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)=(0,1).$ What is the range of the common logarithm when we restrict the domain to $(0,1)$?